# Does an arbitrary instruction pointer reside in a specific function?

Tags: c++, c

I have a very difficult problem I'm trying to solve:  Let's say I have an arbitrary instruction pointer.  I need to find out if that instruction pointer resides in a specific function (let's call it "Foo").

One approach to this would be to try to find the start and ending bounds of the function and see if the IP resides in it.  The starting bound is easy to find:

```
    void *start = &Foo;
```

The problem is, I don't know how to get the ending address of the function (or how "long" the function is, in bytes of assembly).

Does anyone have any ideas how you would get the "length" of a function, or a completely different way of doing this?

Let's assume that there is no SEH or C++ exception handling in the function.  Also note that I am on a win32 platform, and have full access to the win32 api.

Comment: You assume that a function must be a contiguous sequence of bytes in memory. This needs not be the case.

Comment: What are you really trying to do?  Is this for debugging?

Comment: @Pavel: I've never seen a function whose code was not generated as a contiguous sequence. Though I can imagine a hand coded assembly routine being written in such a manner, I have a hard time thinking about a scenario where a compiler would do such a thing. Where would this come up in practice?

Comment: @Dan - I've seen tools that do rearrange code like this.  I don't know if Visual Studio PGO does for sure, but I wouldn't be surprised if it does.  Uncommon code paths in a function (for example, error paths) are moved into a separate part of the image and common code paths are grouped together.  This improves performance because it reduces the total number of pages that need to be brought in for common paths in the code.

Comment: As Michael says, POGO can rearrange code so that some parts of a function are not contiguous. With full global optimization enabled the compiler may also inline arbitrary code so any function (whether defined as inline or not) can be inlined into any other. Then there's COMDAT folding which collapses functions with identical assembly into a single function which will pick up an arbitrary name from the PDB from any of the original functions.

Comment: @Pavel:  Yep, it's definitely the case that the function won't necessarily be in a contiguous region.  I only meant my "within a certain range" to be an example, but I didn't point out the flaw with it.  Even still, for my purposes here, even knowing a "large chunk" of the area is sufficient.

Comment: It should be safe to assume then, that if he is in control of the optimizer, that he can ensure these cases would be rare exceptions (if present at all).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the `*.map` file which can optionally be generated by the linker when it links the program, or at the program's debug (`*.pdb`) file.

Comment: Ah, of course!  I don't know why I didn't think of using the PDB file.  That's what I need to do exactly, thank you.

Answer (score 7):

This won't work.  You're presuming functions are contigous in memory and that one address will map to one function.  The optimizer has a lot of leeway here and can move code from functions around the image.

If you have PDB files, you can use something like the dbghelp or DIA API's to figure this out.  For instance, [SymFromAddr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681323(VS.85).aspx).  There may be some ambiguity here as a single address can map to multiple functions.

I've seen code that tries to do this before with something like:

```
#pragma optimize("", off)
void Foo()
{
}

void FooEnd()
{
}
#pragma optimize("", on)
```

And then FooEnd-Foo was used to compute the length of function Foo.   This approach is incredibly error prone and still makes a lot of assumptions about exactly how the code is generated.

Comment: The best that can be done here is to analyze opcodes starting from pointer to beginning on function, do flow analysis on all possible conditional branches, and figure out if your destination instruction pointer is reachable for some possible input. Naturally, this is extremely architecture-specific (any introduction of new opcodes in new CPUs can break this), and very complicated.

Comment: SymFromAddr is probably the best and most reliable option.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I haven't done assembly in about 15 years.  Back then, I didn't do very much.  Also, it was 680x0 asm.  BUT...

Don't you just need to put a label before and after the function, take their addresses, subtract them for the function length, and then just compare the IP?  I've seen the former done.  The latter seems obvious.

If you're doing this in C, look first for debugging support --- ChrisW is spot on with map files, but also see if your C compiler's standard library provides anything for this low-level stuff -- most compilers provide tools for analysing the stack etc., for instance, even though it's not standard.  Otherwise, try just using inline assembly, or wrapping the C function with an assembly file and a empty wrapper function with those labels.

Answer (score 1):

The most simple solution is maintaining a state variable:

```
volatile int FOO_is_running = 0;

int Foo( int par ){
  FOO_is_running = 1;

  /* do the work */

  FOO_is_running = 0;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I do it, but it's using gcc/gdb.

$ gdb ImageWithSymbols

gdb> info line * 0xYourEIPhere

Edit: Formatting is giving me fits.  Time for another beer.